# CAN bus nulling data at transmission

Tags: c, embedded, microcontroller, stm32, can-bus

I'm trying to transmit some data by CAN bus between two STM32 blue pill MCUs (STM32F103C8T6). The data array to be transmitted is composed by data read from other CAN bus devices, from ADC pins and from an accelerometer/gyroscope I2C module. At the transmitter, I can visualize all the data in the array right before being transmitted using a ST-link debugger. However, at the receptor, I receive all the data correct except for the accel/gyro module ones, that become just zeros.

I tried changing the position of the module data in the array, but still receive zeros at these positions. So, I decided to transmit just the accel/gyro data, but still receive zeros; if I add some dummy data in that array, I receive just the dummy data and zeros. I also tried changing the MCU of reception and turning the array into volatile or static, but nothing new happened. Moreover, I tried processing the data before transmitting, merging the bytes into 16 bit data, converting to float to some scale and finally reconverting into 8 bit data to the CAN bus, but didn't work.

The code below is for read the module; the data at position 0 is just dummy to know if the transmission was successful.

```
void MPU_Read(void){
    uint8_t add, accel_data[6], gyro_data[6];
    int i;

    add = ACCEL_XOUT_H;
    while(HAL_I2C_Master_Transmit(&hi2c2, 0xD0, &add, 1, 1000) != HAL_OK);
    while(HAL_I2C_Master_Receive(&hi2c2, 0xD0, accel_data, 6, 1000) != HAL_OK);

    add = GYRO_XOUT_H;
    while(HAL_I2C_Master_Transmit(&hi2c2, 0xD0, &add, 1, 1000) != HAL_OK);
    while(HAL_I2C_Master_Receive(&hi2c2, 0xD0, gyro_data, 6, 1000) != HAL_OK);

    MPU_data[0] = 0xAF;
    for(i=1;i<6;i++){
        MPU_data[i] = accel_data[i];
    }
    for(i=0;i<6;i++){
        MPU_data[6+i] = gyro_data[i];
    }
}
```

The code below is for transmit the data by CAN bus.

```
void Send_Tel(){
    txHeader.DLC = 8;
    txHeader.StdId = 0x610;
    while(HAL_CAN_AddTxMessage(&hcan, &txHeader, (uint8_t*)&MPU_data[0], &txMailbox)!= HAL_OK);

    txHeader.DLC = 4;
    txHeader.StdId = 0x611;
    while(HAL_CAN_AddTxMessage(&hcan, &txHeader, (uint8_t*)&MPU_data[8], &txMailbox)!= HAL_OK);
}
```

The code below is to receive the data from CAN bus.

```
void HAL_CAN_RxFifo0MsgPendingCallback(CAN_HandleTypeDef *hcan){
    HAL_CAN_GetRxMessage(hcan, CAN_RX_FIFO0, &rxHeader, &can_rx_data[0]);
        if((rxHeader.StdId & 0x0FF0) == 0x610){
            switch(rxHeader.StdId){ 
                case 0x610:
                    for(int j=0; j<=7; j++){
                         data_tel[j] = can_rx_data[j];
                    }
                break;

                case 0x611:
                    for(int j=0; j<=7; j++){
                         data_tel[j+8] = can_rx_data[j];
                    }
                break;  
            }
        flag_can = 0;
    }
}
```

Comment: The word "callback" suggest that these are called from interrupts? If so, you have race conditions all over the place and need to implement a double-buffering method.

Comment: Hard to tell, without seeing the complete code. Could you post it? Esp. the definition of variables on the receiving side.

Comment: I looked up about race condition, but I couldn't find out  where this is happening in my code if so. I shrank up the code at maximum, just sending the accelerometer data (6 bytes), but didn't work. In the link below you can find the main and ISR files of transmitter and receptor. Obs.: there is configuration of some peripherals that I use at the original code but it shouldn't influence on this code.
https://www.mediafire.com/file/v09otjdyhsjckzp/code.rar/file

Comment: I suppose that fields of your can msg are somehow filled with arbitrary values (the fields you are not explicitly setting). Therefore I'd suggest that you check the can msg before transmitting and check if the rtr flag is cleared. If the rtr flag is set the receiver will ignore the data.

Comment: @MarcosMonteiro any activity?